# mgo API - difference between mgo, mgo/bson, mgo/txn

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I recently started learning Go and really like it so far. I would like to learn how to make a REST API with the `mgo` Mongo driver.

At the website, there are three APIs: `mgo`, `mgo/bson`, `mgo/txn`. What do they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Darshan is right: there are good references for those details at the [project website](http://labix.org/mgo). Specifically, you can find links to the package APIs of [mgo](http://labix.org/v2/mgo), [mgo/bson](http://labix.org/v2/mgo/bson), and [mgo/txn](http://labix.org/v2/mgo/txn)

Just providing a quick overview of each of the packages, since this seems missing from the web page (I should fix that):

**[labix.org/v2/mgo](http://labix.org/v2/mgo)**

This is the MongoDB driver itself. If you want to talk to a MongoDB database, this is the package to start with. Have a look at the [mgo.Dial](http://labix.org/v2/mgo#Dial) function, and the example in the [project website](http://labix.org/mgo).

**[labix.org/v2/mgo/bson](http://labix.org/v2/mgo/bson)**

This package implements the marshaling and unmarshaling of BSON documents, following the [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org). It doesn't depend on any of the other two packages, and may be used by itself when one wants to simply serialize/deserialize documents in that format for whatever reason.

The `mgo` package uses it to implement all marshaling and unmarshaling functionality, so the details you find in the documentation of the `mgo/bson` package in terms of field tags, etc, are all valid when working with the `mgo` package as well.

**[labix.org/v2/mgo/txn](http://labix.org/v2/mgo/txn)**

This package implements the mgo-specific [multi-document transaction support for MongoDB](http://blog.labix.org/2012/08/22/multi-doc-transactions-for-mongodb). It implements its functionality on top of the `mgo` package, and neither of the other two packages depends on it. If you're just getting started with your MongoDB use, you most probably don't need this package.

Comment: That clarified things a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They aren't three separate APIs; it's one API that's modularized.  `mgo` is the core package.  `mgo/bson` is the BSON implementation.  `mgo/txn` supports multi-document transactions.

You'd start by just using `mgo` and add either of the subpackages if you need the features they provide.  There's example code at the [mgo homepage](http://labix.org/mgo) that demonstrates usage.

Comment: Could you please explain in a little more detail? What do you mean by BSON implementation and multi-document transactions?

Comment: @tldr There's excellent documentation of all three packages linked to from the mgo homepage.